# How to update the other combo boxes in the new item row of ASPxGridView?

Tags: asp.net, webforms, devexpress

I am writing a web form using controls from DevExpress.

There is a Grid which has 3 GridViewDataComboBoxColumns and I am going to create a SelectedIndexChanged event to update the value of the other combo boxes in newitemrow once one of the combo boxes is filled.

For example, there are 3 columns: EmployeeID, EmployeeName and EmployeeEmail
When I selected a EmployeeID in the newitemrow, then the other two boxes in newitemrow (employeename and employeeemail) will be filled by the SelectedIndexChanged Event.

However, I don't know how to locate the other combo boxes in the SelectedIndexChanged Event.

Please help!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you are using MS UpdatePanel, I would suggest that you use ComboBoxes within the columns' EditItemTemplate and set their AutoPostBack property to true.  Handle the editor's SelectedIndexChanged to update editor values.  Here is the example project:

[How to use cascading comboboxes in an inline edit mode](http://www.devexpress.com/Support/Center/Example/Details/E1358)

Comment: Thank you so much platon.
Since I used the event "GridView_CellEditorInitialize" in Server side instead of using template tag to initialize in client side, grid.FindEditRowCellTemplateControl return NULL value while grid.FindControl(string ID) work for me.

Comment: Another Question....Since I created my custom buttons...
Is it possible to hide the Update and Cancel button in the Edit cell row (newitemrow)?